# Best way of storing data in this scenario using text files?

Tags: python, tkinter, text-files

I am creating a software for a driving school but I'm limited to what plugins are available to me. I also have to use text files for the databases rather than being able to use SQL or the like. I can't seem to figure out this next stage.
This is the scenario:

Each instructor has a unique login, and they can choose to book a lesson onto the calendar/timetable, or just simply view it. The issue is that I'm unsure how to store the data without creating a very large number of text files, because originally my idea was that each instructor would be able to view their own individual calendar/timetable (linked together via their unique login) however because of how the calendar works, each week would require it's own text file and then that number of text files would be multiplied by the total number of instructors.
The code for the calendar and timetable is(not perfectly working but the main principles are there):

```
import sys
import re
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import tkinter.font as Font
import time
import calendar
#from tkinter import font
from tkinter import ttk
def Calendar():

    def mainTimetable():
        #root1 = Tk()

        #frame = Frame(root1)

        days = ["","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
        hours = ["","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00",
                 "16:00","17:00","18:00"]

        class WrappedButtons:
            def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
                self.button = Button(master,font=('Courier'),fg='#333333',bg='#CCCCCC', **kwargs)
                self.name = ''

            def nameToggle(self):
                if not self.name:
                    self.name = nameEntry.get()
                else:
                    self.name = ''
                self.button.config(text=self.name)

        def subTimetable():
            global nameEntry
            popup = Toplevel()
            #popup.title('Timetable')
            for x in range(12):
                Label(popup,font=('Courier'),fg='#333333',bg='#CCCCCC', text=hours[x]).grid(row=x,column=0)
            for x in range(8):
                Label(popup,font=('Courier'),fg='#333333',bg='#CCCCCC',text=days[x]).grid(row=0,column=x)
                if x < 7: # this avoids an extra column of buttons
                    for y in range(11):
                        temp = WrappedButtons(popup,width=20)
                        temp.button.config(command=temp.nameToggle)
                        temp.button.grid(row=y+1,column=x+1)
            Label(popup,text = "Enter the name of pupil and click the slot you wish to fill/remove: ")\
                .grid(row=13,column=0,columnspan=4)

            nameEntry = Entry(popup,width=40)
            nameEntry.grid(row=13,column=4,columnspan=2)


            backButton = Button(popup,font=('Courier'),fg='#333333',bg='#CCCCCC',text='Back',command= popup.destroy)#lambda: [f() for f in[popup.destroy,ownermenu]]).grid(row=13,column=6) # Add functionality to return to user page
            submitButton = Button(popup,text='Submit Data').grid(row=13,column=7)

            menubar = Menu(popup)
            filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
            filemenu.add_command(label='Home',command=lambda:[f() for f in [popup.destroy,home1]])
            filemenu.add_separator()
            filemenu.add_command(label='Exit',command=popup.destroy)
            menubar.add_cascade(label='Page',menu=filemenu)
            popup.config(menu=menubar)

            popup.configure(bg='#333333')

            #popup.overrideredirect(True)
            #popup.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(popup.winfo_screenwidth(), popup.winfo_screenheight()))

        subTimetable()
        #root.mainloop()


    root = Tk()
    root.title('Calendar')
    root.configure(bg='#333333')
    permanentFrame,newFrame = Frame(root), Frame(root)
    permanentFrame.pack(side='top')
    newFrame.pack(side='top')

    months = {1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30, 7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31}

    lbMonths = Label(permanentFrame,text='Months: ',fg='#333333',bg='#CCCCCC')
    lbMonths.pack()
    dropMonths = ttk.Combobox(permanentFrame, values=list(months.keys()))
    dropMonths.pack()


    class ButtonsWrap:
        def __init__(self,master,month,day, **kwargs):
            self.button = Button(master,**kwargs)
            self.monthInd = month-1
            self.dayInd = day-1
            self.toplevel = False
            self.thing = None

        def popClose(self):
            self.thing.destroy()
            self.toplevel = False
            self.thing = None

        def popup(self):
            if not self.toplevel:
                self.thing = Toplevel()
                self.toplevel = True
                #Label(self.thing, command=mainTimetable).pack()
                self.popClose
                mainTimetable()
                self.thing.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.popClose) #Add back in when 'back' functionality is complete



    buttons = []

    def makeCalendar(blank):
        curMonth = int(dropMonths.get())

        for i in buttons:
            if i.thing:
                i.thing.destroy()
        for i in newFrame.slaves():
            i.destroy()

        rows = [Frame(newFrame) for i in range(5)]
        [i.pack() for i in rows]

        curDay = 1

        for i in range(35):
            if len(rows[0].slaves()) == 7:
                rows.pop(0)
            temp = ButtonsWrap(rows[0], curMonth,curDay,text='',height=1,width=2)
            temp.button.pack(side='left')
            buttons.append(temp)
            if curDay <= months[curMonth]:
                temp.button.config(text=curDay,command=temp.popup)
                curDay += 1

    dropMonths.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', makeCalendar)
    menubar = Menu(root)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label='Home',command=lambda:[f() for f in [root.destroy,home1]])
    filemenu.add_separator()
    filemenu.add_command(label='Exit',command=root.destroy)
    menubar.add_cascade(label='Page',menu=filemenu)
    root.config(menu=menubar)

    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))

    root.mainloop()
Calendar()
```

It works by allowing the instructor to type into the timetable, and then my aim is to save the timetable so that it can be referenced in the future (so it doesn't reset every time it's closed). What would be an efficient way of achieving my goal?

Feel free to ask questions if I've poorly explained the problem, as I feel I may have.

Comment: What exactly is forcing the use of text files? Can't you even use SQLite?

Comment: @roganjosh It’s just the limitations of the project, I presume it’s to test coding ability ? It’s been argued that it’s a bit impractical but there has been no change

Comment: In that case I'm not sure we can really improve on your idea. You'll presumably have to split it out by instructor and by week because very quickly your performance will degrade as you have to keep parsing more and more data. Maybe prefix each file name with the driver_id, then underscore, and the week commencing date. Something that you could quickly try and use to identify the file.

Comment: @roganjosh an idea I had was to have a universal timetable, and then each instructor has their own unique colour (or similar idea) so that it would be easy to distinguish (with a key possibly) which information is for each instructor. This would mean I only have one text file for each week which is more reasonable however im unsure how I’d go about storing it in a text file using this idea.

Comment: *"What would be an efficient way of achieving my goal?"*: Don't look for `efficiens`, look for *simplicity*. Use a `dict {<date>: [<time table>]}`, save the `dict` as CSV.